# JS Autocomplete - Fire event on document onchange, with value from autocomplete function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS

I currently have two functions.

The both work as they should.

However, I cannot use the value from the first document function and fire the onchange event in the second and use the selected value.

I would like the selected value from the first script to fire the onchange event in the second script.

Please help!

Html:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="product[]" placeholder="Product" 
    class="product" 
     onfocus="javascript:$(this).autocomplete('search','');"> 
</td>
```

1: Auto complete:

```
$(function () {

    var validOptions = <? echo $get_product_names  ?>;
    previousValue = "";

    $(".product")
        .autocomplete({
            source: validOptions,
            select: function( event, ui ) {alert($(this).val())},
            minLength: 0
        }).keyup(function () {
        var isValid = false;
        for (i in validOptions) {
            if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isValid) {
            this.value = previousValue
        } else {
            previousValue = this.value;
        }
    }).click(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
    });
});
```

2nd: Generate Pricing:

```
$(document).on('change', '.product, .width, .drop', function () {

    var product = $(".product", $(this).parent().parent()).val();

    //alert(product);

    var width = $(".width", $(this).parent().parent()).val();
    var drop = $(".drop", $(this).parent().parent()).val();

    var sub_total = $(".total", $(this).parent().parent());


    if (product === "" || width === "" || drop === "") {
        var parent = sub_total.val(0);
    }


    if (product !== "" && width !== "" && drop !== "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "#",
            method: "POST",
            data: {

                "product": product,
                "width": width,
                "drop": drop

            },
            success: function (data) {

                if (data === "") {

                    var parent = sub_total.val(0);

                }
                else {
                    var parent = sub_total.val(data);
                }
                calculate(parent);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers:

I switched over to [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

My code looks like this now.

```
<td>
   <select data-placeholder="Choose Type" name="product[]"
           class="product chosen-select" tabindex="2"
           style="width: 150px">

          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option> 
          <option value="3">3</option>                  
   </select>

</td>
```

js:

```
//trigger product change
$('.product').click(function () {
    $('.product').trigger("chosen:updated");
});


$(document).on('change', '.product, .width, .drop', function () {

var product = $(".product", $(this).parent().parent()).val();

//alert(product);

var width = $(".width", $(this).parent().parent()).val();
var drop = $(".drop", $(this).parent().parent()).val();

var sub_total = $(".total", $(this).parent().parent());


if (product === "" || width === "" || drop === "") {
    var parent = sub_total.val(0);
}


if (product !== "" && width !== "" && drop !== "") {
    $.ajax({
        url: "#",
        method: "POST",
        data: {

            "product": product,
            "width": width,
            "drop": drop

        },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data === "") {

                var parent = sub_total.val(0);

            }
            else {
                var parent = sub_total.val(data);
            }
            calculate(parent);
        }
    });
}
});
```